# Ubuntu not booting - existing pxe rom,no bootable device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire R3-131T.
when I boot the device from the usb drive, I get a black screen with instructions that say :
Existing PXE ROM
No bootable device -- insert disk and press any key

Answer (score 0):

You most liekly need to change the boot order to allow booting from USB.

During boot, keep hitting F2 and DEL until you end up in the BIOS.

Change to the tab "Boot", and put the USB interface in first place. Save, exit and reboot, you should now be booting from your USB stick.

BTW, PXE is network boot. You might want to disable that.

Comment: I changed the boot order and booted the pc from the USB
the error still appears

Comment: How can an "Unable to boot" error occur if the system boots like you just said?